# Jquery versions conflict web host

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this code that i need to get working in my webpage ,it actually works offline,but when i upload it to mi web page it does not works. i have conducted several test and i know it is becouse of the two version of jquery,but those are necesaries for the calendar and the get instruction which is very important to the use of the program. the first part is to the calendar to work and the jquery version 1.12.0 is for the use of the get instruction.

some ideas?

the web platform is one.com

```
   <!DOCTYPE html >


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });


function revtemp() {
$.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CG2a49fTJyXxk9CUFNpX4dueGGhxfxmtTZkN5wj0U80/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+K", function(data){
da=data;      
alert(da);   
        },"text");
}


window.setInterval(revtemp,5000);
 </script>


</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  <label> Seleccionar Fecha:</label>
  <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" size="12" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no ......... Why the heck would you use a seven year old version of jQuery to get the datepicker working.

Comment: I know it is old,but i am really an outsider to this king of code,what do you suggest?

Comment: Use ***one*** version of jQuery, included just ***once***, *always* ! You can use the current version of jQuery with the current version of jQuery UI, and have both a datepicker and the instructions

Comment: I already changed it,but still dont work on my  web page    check the source code . the $get is not working  view-source:http://lavadito.com.mx/pt.html

Comment: It's working as it should, but Google doesn't support cross-origin requests due to the same-origin policy

Comment: and if you dont mind me asking, how can I solve that issue?

Comment: Isolved it using a cors server,but  I was wondering if it can work better using a php server that is within my same domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can load Jquery on this way to
One in on header or other in footer.

- or you can verify that header jquery is loaded or not in footer section.

  if ((typeof jQuery == 'undefined') || (jQuery.fn.jquery != "1.9.1")) {
                  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Responsive/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));   
              }